# Replace some Characters in a String

Tags: c#, string

I have this String

```
link="https%3a%2f%2fen.wikipedia.org%2fwiki%2fHuawei/"
```

which shoud be like this:

```
link="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei/"
```

I wrote this code:

```
link.Replace("%2f", "/");
link.Replace("%3a", ":");
```

But it did not work.

Comment: You forgot to assign your variable: `link = link.Replace("%2f", "/");` and `link = link.Replace("%3a", ":");`

Comment: Replace works. There are dozens of duplicate questions already. Another one was asked today

Comment: What means "doesn´t work"? Please be more specific on what you´ve tried and what you expect to get and what you get instead.

Comment: *"it did not work"* - extremely poor problem description. Please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there are so many duplicates I cannot even decide which one to mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to decode the URL yourself I'd use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("https%3a%2f%2fen.wikipedia.org%2fwiki%2fHuawei/")
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei/"
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

String.Replace does return the value replaced try:

```
link = link.Replace("%2f", "/");
```

Comment: Storing the result on the same variable is going to cause additional confusion

Answer (score 0):

link is a string and is not mutating when you call the `Replace` method

`link.Replace` will not affect the link object itself, instead [it returns a new String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx)
from the doc emphasis mine:

> **Returns a new string** in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode
>   character in this instance are replaced with another specified Unicode
>   character.

do instead:

```
link = link.Replace("%2f", "/");   or
link = link.Replace("%3a", ":");
```